# Add Windows 8.1 user: Service unavailable

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-live

When I try to add a user with Microsoft Live account via PC-Settings (German Windows 8.1) I get the message "The service is currently unavailable. Please try again later.", for several days now. While logging on at login.live.com works as expected. Any insights what this could be about? Or anyone else with this problem?

Comment: This a recent problem.  Have you ever been able to link your account? 8.1 or 8.0?

Comment: Joke: The NSA's doing some upgrades, things will work again shortly. As soon as they can snoop some bank info, to help pay down the US debt. ;)

Comment: Yes, the account is linked on another PC. And other accounts are already linked on that PC.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP noted in a comment on an answer almost 1 year ago that the problem is no longer reproducible or fixable.

Comment: Hmm, even if fixed it is not off-topic, is it?

Comment: This is an almost 2 yr old problem.  If you still need an answer, I'll retract my close vote.  The answer you commented on has been deleted & I forget exactly what you wrote, but you indicated that the problem could no longer be reproduced.  If so, there is no way to determine if any answer is the solution.  Just asking for insights is requesting opinions, which is off-topic.  A poll about who else has the problem is also off-topic.  Is this a problem you're currently facing, and are you in a position to determine whether a solution works?  If you solved it, post an answer with your solution.